# How to plot an implicit function with real and complex solutions, different line styles/colours, and a double y-axis?

Tags: plotting, equation-solving

I am new to Mathematica and trying to reproduce the following figure using `ContourPlot`:

[image]

(From: https://iopscience.iop.org/article/10.1088/1402-4896/abb2e0/meta)

My code:

```
n1 = 0.5
n2 = 0.5
sig1 = 0.1
sig2 = 0.1
U1 = -1
U2 = 1

ContourPlot[n1/((Omg - K*U1)^2 - 3*K^2*sig1) + n2/((Omg - K*U2)^2 - 3*K^2*sig2) - 1/K^2 == 1, 
           {K, 0, 1}, {Omg, -2, 2}, Axes -> True, Exclusions -> 
           {(Omg - K*U1)^2 - 3*K^2*sig1 ==  0, (Omg - K*U2)^2 - 3*K^2*sig2 == 0}]
```

The output:

[image]

As seen in the output plot, `ContourPlot` only returns and plots the real solutions.

Is there another Mathematica function that plots both the complex and real solutions with different line styles, and a double axis as shown in the first figure?

I am using Mathematica 10. I tried to use `ReImPlot` but no luck.

The code for 'ReImPlot':

```
ReImPlot[n1/((Omg - K*U1)^2 - 3*K^2*sig1) + n2/((Omg - K*U2)^2 - 3*K^2*sig2) - 1/K^2 == 1, {K, 0, 1}, {Omg, -2, 2}, Axes -> True, Exclusions -> 
   {(Omg - K*U1)^2 - 3*K^2*sig1 ==  0, (Omg - K*U2)^2 - 3*K^2*sig2 == 0}]
```

The output:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Let me show you part of the job.

Using leftsided equation==0 and splitting Omg into real and imaginary part. `{Omg -> o1 + I o2}` Then taking real an imaginary part of equation and eliminating o2 for real plot and o1 for imaginary plot.

```
n1 = 1/2;
n2 = 1/2;
sig1 = 1/10;
sig2 = 1/10;
U1 = -1
U2 = 1

feq = Subtract @@ (n1/((Omg - K*U1)^2 - 3*K^2*sig1) + 
      n2/((Omg - K*U2)^2 - 3*K^2*sig2) - 1/K^2 == 1);

ceRe = ComplexExpand[
  Re[feq /. {Omg -> o1 + I o2} // Together // Numerator], 
  TargetFunctions -> {Re, Im}]

ceIm = ComplexExpand[
  Im[feq /. {Omg -> o1 + I o2} // Together // Numerator], 
  TargetFunctions -> {Re, Im}]

(tho1 = Thread[
    o1 == (o1 /. 
        Solve[{ceRe == 0, ceIm == 0, 0 < K < 1, -2 < o1 < 2}, 
         o1, {o2}, Reals] // FullSimplify)]) // TableForm


tho2 = Thread[
  o2 == (o2 /. 
      Solve[{ceRe == 0, ceIm == 0, 0 < K < 1, -1/10 < o2 < 1/10}, 
       o2, {o1}, Reals] // FullSimplify)]

{cp1 = ContourPlot[Evaluate[tho1[[All, 1]]], {K, 0, 1}, {o1, -2, 2}, 
   PlotPoints -> 80, Exclusions -> Sqrt[3/7] == K], 
 cp2 = ContourPlot[
   Evaluate[tho2[[All, 1]]], {K, 0, 1}, {o2, -8/100, 8/100}, 
   PlotPoints -> 30, Exclusions -> Sqrt[3/7] == K]}
```

[image]

Leave it to you to combine both plots the way you like.

Get explicit solutions with Solve

```
sol = Solve[{ceRe == 0, ceIm == 0, 0 < K < 1}, {o1, o2}, Reals] // 
   FullSimplify

{Plot[Evaluate[o1 /. sol], {K, 0, 1}], 
 Plot[Evaluate[o2 /. sol], {K, 0, 1}]}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for a well-presented answer. If I may ask, how did calculate the K = sqrt(3/7) part?

Comment: Solve gives you `ConditionalExpression[
 o1 ==....., 
 0 < K < Sqrt[3/7] || Sqrt[3/7] < K < 1]` . Says K==Sqrt]3/7] is excluded.